# I declared a bool type before my parameter($val) within a function(my_fnc)

Tags: php, casting, type-declaration

I passed a argument by value that string "foo" and no error generated but I know that if I declared a bool, I could only passed Boolean value otherwise it will throw a TypeError Exception in php 7.

here i given my code of example

```
function my_fnc(bool $val){
       echo $val;
      }

my_fnc("hellow");
```

When I executed there was no error. Why?

I know strict_types but in this type(weak type) why did I not get an error and how did it work?

Answer (score 0):

It works because you have not declared that strict_types should be enabled. The very first line in your program needs to be `declare(strict_types=1);` to enforce strict types. If you change your example as shown below you will get an error thrown as expected.

```
declare(strict_types=1);
function my_fnc(bool $val){
       echo $val;
      }

my_fnc("hellow");
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to my_fnc() must be
>   of the type bool, string given